# Can I use react-native-i18n library with react-native-web-boilerplate

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs

Can I use [react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) library with [react-native-web-boilerplate](https://github.com/agrcrobles/react-native-web-boilerplate)?

`react-native-web-boilerplate` is a library ([description here](https://medium.com/@locropulenton/navigating-in-all-platforms-with-react-navigation-673e9a6e963)) using which you can build an app in react and navigate in desktop, mobile and web platforms.

I was trying my luck with `react-native-i18n` library but `react-native-i18n` import fails.

`RNI18n` object returned as undefined. I can't get current locale, language.

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n'
```

Has anyone tried using `react-native-i18n` in a cross platform app?

Or is there any other better way you would like to suggest.

Comment: You can try to inject a property `RNI18n` into NativeModules, just see https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/blob/master/index.js, it depends a constant named `RNI18n.languages`, and a method named `RNI18n.getLanguages`. You should ensure inject it before it be imported.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you please post answer and show me how to inject this property?

Comment: I just created a patch based on react-native-web-boilerplate at https://gist.github.com/cpunion/d66b71342b9a3c1818ad14f9885a0701. Important: change `import` to `require` to ensure module importing order.

Comment: Great. One thing I noticed, your solution binds to French language. I would rather want my app to auto detect the current locale on device it is running and render the app accordingly.

Comment: That's what react-native-i18n does. There's this 'native'ness

Comment: Because `react-native-web` run in browser, you can use `navigator.language` to get current language, and `navigator.languages` to get a language list. `navigator` is a global variable.

Comment: Cool. That should work. Could you please post an answer. I will test it and mark it answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149308/discussion-between-jacky-lee-and-user1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a constant `RNI18n` into `NativeModules` of `react-native`, because `react-native-i18n` depends that. And then ensure to execute it before other modules, likes below:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const languages = [navigator.language]

NativeModules.RNI18n = {
    languages,
    getLanguages: () => Promise.resolve(languages)
}

const App = require('./src').default // If it's ES6 module
```

`require` will keep the order of execution, if you import other modules by `import statement`, maybe it run first, the `injection` will invalid.